# How can I remove .html extension from ALL internal links in Wordpress posts using PHPMYADMIN

Tags: sql, wordpress, url, url-rewriting, phpmyadmin

I rebuilt an old Wordpress website with 1000+ articles. We removed the .html extension from URLs, and successfully implemented a .htaccess 301 redirect from .html urls to non .html urls.

**Problem** - I would like a SQL query to remove all .html extensions hard-coded into the Wordpress posts, to avoid huge numbers of unnecessary redirects. 
**Caveat** - the query must only remove .html on internal links.

The query would look something like this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://example.com/***/link.html', 'http://example.com/***/link');
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: If you are using phpmyadmin, why not just export the database, run a regex search and replace in your favourite text editor and re-import?

Comment: That would be possible @CUGreen, but what I really need is the pattern that will accept any string in the url (the *** part above), so taking care to replace only if it is a completely formed internal link (with particular attention that there are no spaces). I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere.

Comment: I guess a pattern could be something like this ```(https?:\/\/(www\.)?yourdomain.com\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)).html```

Comment: I got it down to something like the expression below, but not sure what to do about the '???':    UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://example.com/[-a-zA-Z0-9_/].html', 'http://example.com/???');

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `REPLACE` does not support regular expressions.

You will need to use a MySQL user-defined function (UDF) from an external library. eg. https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp.

Or you can attempt to write your own such as this https://techras.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/regex-replace-for-mysql/

I hope that information will help you.